# Merging powershell scripts

Tags: powershell

I am configuring Jenkins, and when the check out is performed, I need 2 folders to be deleted. I have created the script, which deletes all the bin folder. However, I want to delete all obj folder too.

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\testFolderCheck 'obj' -Recurse -force |
Remove-Item -force -Recurse 
Get-ChildItem -path C:\testFolderCheck 'bin' -Recurse -force | 
Remove-Item -force -Recurse
```

When I am executing this scripts, only the bin folder is getting deleted. Is there any way of executing both scripts in one run?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of paths to the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet :

```
Get-ChildItem [[-Path] <String[]> ] [[-Filter] <String> ] [-Exclude <String[]> ] [-Force] [-Include <String[]> ] [-Name] [-Recurse] [-UseTransaction] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

So try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\testFolderCheck\obj', 'C:\testFolderCheck\bin' -Recurse -force |
    Remove-Item -force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean
{
    Get-ChildItem -path C:\testFolderCheck 'obj' -Recurse -force | Remove-Item -force -Recurse 
    Get-ChildItem -path C:\testFolderCheck 'bin' -Recurse -force | Remove-Item -force -Recurse
}

clean
```

One possibility to excute the script in one run is to define a function. Another possibility is to use the *invoke-command with computername and your script as scriptblock* (maybe the better way, if you do remoting).

Don´t be to hard -it´s my first post on stackoverflow :-)